# ListPlot and Show n plots from two lists with large n

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

For the context, I have been dealing with Random Matrices and Dyson Brownian motion.

I have two lists, the first one contains the number of steps, so

```
steps={0,1,2...,s} ;
```

the second one contains a list of the eigenvalues of the matrix, calculated at each step, so it looks like this

```
eigenvalues={{x1_0,x2_0,...,xn_0},{x1_1,x2_1,...,xn_1},...,{x1_s,x2_s,...,xn_s}},
```

in which `{x1_0, x2_0,...,xn_0}` are n initial eigenvalues at `steps=0` and so on.

Now if I only need to `ListPlot` `x1` as a function of `s`, it is easy

```
grid1 = Transpose@{steps, eigenvalues[[All, 1]]};

p1 = ListLinePlot[grid1[[All, {1, 2}]]] ,
```

but what if I want to plot and show together n plots like that with n, let's say, equals to 100?

I'm new to *Mathematica* but I know how to use `Map` or `MapThread` in basic ways.

Comment: The last row of your Eigenvalues should be `{x1_s, x2_s, ..., xn_s}`, right? Just trying to understand your issue...

Comment: have a look at `Multicolumn` (I assume you want 100 separate plots not one plot with 100 lines )

Comment: @george2079. Not necessarily. [Plots of adiabatic potential curves](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lDipb.png) with lots of eigenvalues shown are pretty popular in the AMO (atomic, molecular, and optical) physics community.

Comment: `Thread[{steps, #}] & /@ Transpose@eigenvalues`

Comment: @Kay Right! Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @march Yes, exactly, I want all the eigenvalues on the same plot! Although in this case it is inflationary cosmology.

Comment: Inflationary cosmology, ultracold molecules, what's the difference? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea, if this is what you are looking for, but I will give it a try:

As I do not know your values, I assigned some ugly values to `step` and `eigenvalues` on my own. The outcome is a sequence of integers:

```
steps = Range[1, 10];
s = Max[steps];
n = 20;
eigenvalues = Table[Range[n], {s}];
```

Than the rearranging brings:

```
someTable = Table[Transpose[{steps, eigenvalues[[All, m]]}], {m, 1, n}];
ListLinePlot[someTable]
```

The result, a lot of lines...

[image]